# Python Pandas Dataframe Control Flow

Tags: python

I have a data frame with a wage column that specifies an hourly wage and a union column that specifies whether or not an employee is in a union. There are other variables too, but they don't matter right now. I'm trying to find the average wage for employees in a union. I've written the code that provides a True/False list of whether or not an employee is in a union. However, I don't know how to apply that list in order to get an average wage. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#Read cps.csv file
import pandas as pd
cps_df = pd.read_csv('cps.csv')
cps_df

#Function to determine whether or not an employee is in a union
def hourly_wage(x):
""" return true if union else false """

if x['union'] == 'Union':
    return True
else:
    return False

#Function to create a list of union vs non-union
def union_list(y):
    """ return a list determining union vs non-union """

    return [hourly_wage(x) for index, x in y.iterrows()]

#Print list
%time
print(union_list(cps_df))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but why not `cps_df[cps_df[''union']=='Union']['wage'].mean()` ?

Comment: I'm required to create a pandas data frame and compute the average hourly wage of a unionized worker by using control flow to iterate through each row of the data frame. So I'm guessing I need to set it up like this. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can do it in a more convenient way. Pandas is great for such things.

Let's assume that wage column is 'wage'. Then code will look as following:

```
import pandas as pd
cps_df = pd.read_csv('cps.csv')
print('Union workers mean wage: ', cps_df[cps_df.union == 'Union'].wage.mean())
```

What it essentially does:
1. Selects all union workers (cps_df[cps_df.union == 'Union'])
2. Aplies mean() function to their wages (.wage.mean())

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I know there's definitely more simplistic ways to get the mean. However, I'm required to use this process. Also, I'll need to know how to do it this way for more complicated scenarios.

Comment: So I guess it is a big data problem. Why don't you collect wages then using your indicator function hourly_wage(x)?

Comment: I mean something like that:

def union_wage_list(y):
    """ return a wages list determining of union workers """

    return [x['wage'] for index, x in y.iterrows() if hourly_wage(x)]

Comment: `def union_wage_list(y): 
""" return a wages list determining of union workers """ 

return [x['wage'] for index, x in y.iterrows() if hourly_wage(x)]`